# Get readings from duplicate names in CSV file Python

Tags: python

I am fairly new at Python and am having some issues reading in my csv file. There are sensor names, datestamps and readings in each column. However, there are multiple of the same sensor name, which I have already made a list of the different options called OPTIONS, shown below

```
OPTIONS = []

with open('sensor_data.csv', 'rb') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] not in OPTIONS:
            OPTIONS.append(row[0])
        sensor_name = row[0]
        datastamp = row[1]
        readings = float(row[2]) 
        print(OPTIONS)
```

Options 
[prints fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUhnE.png),

But now I am having issues retrieving any readings, and using them to calculate average and maximum readings for each unique sensor name.

here are [a few lines of sensor_data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWyeS.png), which goes from 2018-01-01 to 2018-12-31 for sensor_1 to sensor_25.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to print out the correct readings by adding `print(readings)` before the `print(OPTIONS)`? Could you show the 2-3 sample lines of the file sensor_data.csv?

Comment: I was able to print out the  correct readings in the for loop, but outside of the for loop print(readings) displays 5.0. I will edit the post to show some sample code, as the csv is quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have for the `readings` variable is just the reading of each row. One way to get the average readings is to keep track of the sum and count of readings (`sum_readings` and `count_readings` respectively) and then after the for loop you can get the average by dividing the sum with the count. You can get the maximum by initializing a `max_readings` variable with a reading minimum value (I assume to be 0) and then update the variable whenever the current reading is larger than `max_readings` (`max_readings < readings`)

```
import csv

OPTIONS = []
OPTIONS_READINGS = {}

with open('sensor_data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] not in OPTIONS:
            OPTIONS.append(row[0])
            OPTIONS_READINGS[row[0]] = []
        sensor_name = row[0]
        datastamp = row[1]
        readings = float(row[2]) 
        print(OPTIONS)
        OPTIONS_READINGS[row[0]].append(readings)

for option in OPTIONS_READINGS:
    print(option)
    readings = OPTIONS_READINGS[option]
    print('Max readings:', max(readings))
    print('Average readings:', sum(readings) / len(readings))
```

Edit: Sorry I misread the question. If you want to get the maximum and average of each unique options, there is a more straight forward way which is to use an additional dictionary-type variable `OPTIONS_READINGS` whose keys are the option names and the values are the list of readings. You can find the maximum and average reading of an options by simply using the expression `max(OPTIONS_READINGS[option])` and `sum(OPTIONS_READINGS[option]) / len(OPTIONS_READINGS[option])` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I wanted to do this for each sensor name and their respective readings? There are 25 of them after all.  This seems like it does it for all of the rows for every sensor.

Comment: @KF18290 Ok I've updated my answer so that it store each sensor name and their readings. Let me know if it is the desired output.

Comment: It works, but now I would like to store the name of the sensor, the maximum variable and the average variable into a table for all twenty five, along with the number of outlier readings, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version below

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

readings = defaultdict(list)

with open('sensor_data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        readings[row[0]].append(float(row[2]) )

for sensor_name,values in readings.items():
    print('Sensor: {}, Max readings: {}, Avg: {}'.format(sensor_name,max(values), sum(values)/ len(values)))
```